# Expectation of Reciprocal of Average of Variables.

Tags: limits, probability-theory, expected-value, law-of-large-numbers

I'm considering such a question:

Suppose that there are $n$ i.i.d. variables denoted as $X_1,\cdots,X_n$, and a sequence is defined as:
$a_n=\mathbb{E}\left (\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^NX_i}\right)$. It's easy to know that $a_n=\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^NX_i}\right){\geq}\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}\left (\sum_{i=1}^nX_i/n\right)}=\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}(X)}$, and the limitation of $a_n$ **may be** $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\mathbb{E}\left (\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}(X)}\right)=\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}(X)}$. The question is: what is the convergence speed of $a_n\to\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}(X)}$?

According to simulation, the convergence speed seems like $\mathscr{O}(\frac{1}{n})$, but I wonder why.

*Notes: **May be** here means I'm not sure whether the order of expectation and limitation can be exchanged here. It seems like correct through simulation results.*

Comment: Thank you very much! And any papers or materials about this would also help a lot!

Comment: Emmmm.. Textbooks are also OK, since I really have no idea on it! Thanks again!